# what exactly is the winsys in gallium 3D Architecture?

Tags: mesa

I found I could not understand the winsys interface in gallium 3D Architecture.What is the winsys module? What is the relationship between winsys and X server?

Answer (score 5):

winsys is the bridge between Gallium3D and the operating systems. So when you are implementing a driver the winsys for Linux is DRI, for Windows GDI.